# Valor extraño con double en un metodo

Tags: c, function, double

estoy intentando utilizar la funcion || y && para valores de tipo double, el problema es que siempre que ingreso un valor incluso mayor al que pido en el if me manda el mensaje que no corresponde y si imprimo los numeros guardados me aparece un valor que no tiene logica.

El codigo es este: https://pastebin.com/eZnM37KL

El problema es en double func5() y double func6()

Linea 166 y 196

```
double func5(){
  double a,b;

  printf("Realiazamos en esta funcion OR: \n");
  printf("Introduce una valor decimal: ");
  fflush(stdin);//Limpiar buffer
  scanf("%f",&a);
  printf("Introduce otra valor decimal: ");
  fflush(stdin);//Limpiar buffer
  scanf("%f",&b);

  if(a>500.500||b>500.500){
    printf("\nEl primer valor es mayor a 150.5 o el segundo mayor a 100.5");
    printf("\n %f %f",a,b); //IMPRIME EL NUMERO GUARDADO EN A Y B
  }else{
    printf("\nEl primer valor no es mayor a 150.5 ni el segundo a 100.5");
    printf("\n %f %f",a,b);
  }
}

double func6(){
  double a,b;

  printf("Realiazamos en esta funcion OR: \n");
  printf("Introduce una valor decimal: ");
  //fflush(stdin);//Limpiar buffer
  scanf("%f",&a);
  printf("Introduce otra valor decimal: ");
  //fflush(stdin);//Limpiar buffer
  scanf("%f",&b);

  if(a>100&&b>100){
    printf("\nEl primer valor es mayor a 100 y el seguno igual");
    printf("\n %f %f",a,b); //IMPRIME EL NUMERO GUARDADO EN A Y B
  }else{
    printf("\nO el primer valor no es mayor a 100 o el segundo a 100");
    printf("\n %f %f",a,b); //IMPRIME EL NUMERO GUARDADO EN A Y B
  }
}
```

Este es el valor que me aparece:
[image: Como ven pido un valor mayor a 500 doy 600 y sale ese numero y el mensaje que no corresponde]

Lo que espero del programa es que si ingreso un valor que cumpla el if me mande el mensaje sino me mande el else y que el valor que se almacena sea el correcto.

Comment: No utilices enlaces externos para mostrar el código, te sugiero indentar a 4 espacios en el editor de la pregunta, asi se vera con formato de código y sera mas facil reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Lo hago por comodidad pero a que te refieres?

Comment: Puedes revisar cualquier pregunta en el sitio y las veras con un formato `similar a este;`, eso es mas facil para nosotros los que intentamos reproducir tu problema, no tenemos que ir a otros enlaces para poder ver donde esta lo que falla.

Comment: Pero entonces pongo el código que da problema o todo?

Comment: Preferiblemente la función que da problemas, lo que esperas por resultado y lo que actualmente pasas a la función para obtener ese resultado.

Comment: Ya lo puse, e igual lo que espero, el problema tambien es que ingrese el valor que ingrese aún así cumpla el IF no me regresa el mensaje correspondiente y el número que almacena es como la imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes el mismo problema en las 2 funciones que muestras:

```
double a, b;
...
scanf( "%f", ... );
```

Declaras tus variables como `double`, y luego usas el *especificador* `%f` en `scanf( )`.

`%f` espera un dato `float`. Tu usas `double`. El segundo es mas *ancho* que el primero. No leerás bien la entrada.

2 soluciones:

- Cambia el tipo de tus variables a `float`:

`float a, b;`

Y modifica adecuadamente los *literales* que usas:

```
if( a > 500.500f || b > 500.500f ) {
```

- Cambia el *especificador* en tus llamadas a `scanf( )`. Para indicar un `double`, se usa `"%lf"`:

  `scanf( "%lf", &a );`

En teoría **no tendrías que cambiarlo** para `printf( )`, pero tampoco pasa nada si lo haces.

Aparte de lo anterior:

- ¿porqué declaras tus funciones como `double func5( ... )` y luego no devuelves nada ? Declararas como `void func5( ... )`.
- `if( a > 500.500 || b > 500.500 )` no se corresponde con los mensajes que muestras.
- Ídem para `if( a > 100 && b > 100 )`.

Las 2 últimas, espero que sean valores *arbitrarios* que usas para tus pruebas; es claramente erróneo.

Comment: Gracias por contestar!!, me resolviste el problema, no sabía que lf era para double, el maestro siempre decía que era usar f igual que la float pero no tiene mucho sentido. A tus preguntas: 1.- Sé que si no regreso nada no tiene ningún sentido usar una funcion, que es mejor void, el problema es mi maestro que lo pide así, a pesar de que realmente no sirve de nada tenerlo como función. 2.- Sí nada que ver con los mensajes, era para probar, pero debí cambiarlos antes de subirlos. 3.- Si es idem igual, lo mismo, no tiene sentido alguno el mensaje con el IF. Muchas gracias por responder!

Comment: @OscarD si tu maestro te pide que retornes un numero, tal vez deberias modificar tu algoritmo... para que si lo haga